# Calculating time elapsed for each datapoint (Python, Excel, PowerQuery)

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Help needed
I am a beginner in data analytics.
I have a dataset of a measuring device that measures weight(in kg) every minute.

E.g. dataset

```
Value         time
150kg      00:01:00
150kg      00:02:02
150kg      00:03:01
700kg      00:04:04
700kg      00:05:05
1100kg     00:06:07
1100kg     00:07:01
```

I need to calculate the total time elapsed when the weight was 150kg until it was 700kg. Calculate time for 700kg until its 1100kg and so on.

I managed to get the answer using python pandas and for loop. But I was wondering if there is a simple and better way to do this like in an Excel, Power Query or Power BI.

Comment: Seems like you better be more focused in your question. You want to compare instruments?

Comment: What is the "and so on". Why did you pick 700 and 1100, and what is the next in the sequence

Comment: What do you mean by `simple [...] way [...] like in an Excel, Power Query or Power BI.`?